# What's wrong when to nested classes needed to create an object using decorator pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

Recently I try actively to use basic design patterns. But I end up these types of objects creation in my factories

```
$aStandardField = new Viewable(new Translatable(new Errorable(new Validatable(new Viewable(new FormField())))));
```

the `$aStandardField` is an object that if it has a value , it's value is validatable and if there is an Error , the error id will be registered there, and the error is viewable on the top of the field .... .
This code looks smelly to me. So the question is how can I keep my classes small while keeping the core (FormField in the above example) untouched ,using the decorator pattern?

Comment: I do not understand how your classes wouldn't be small with that amount of feature segregation? Is that really your question?

Comment: @plalx the question is if this segregation good or not ?

Comment: Well, if you need that amount of flexibility then perhaps, but it's very hard to tell. Ask yourself what good it brings you and what problem you tried to solve by implementing every single feature as a decorator. You might be overengineering the design.

Comment: @plalx I need this. The point is I don't know why other web frameworks which are supposed to be french wrenches do not have such utilities for the forms. That's why I thought I might be on the wrong rails.

Comment: Perhaps they felt confident that most fields would be visible, validatable, etc. and they built these features right into field. An invisible field could be a field where the draw method was overriden to do nothing for instance while a non-validatable field could be a field where the validate method always returns true. My point is that decorators are perhaps not the only way to achieve what you are trying to achieve. However if you are confident you need that level of extensibility and flexibility then perhaps it's the right design for what you are building.

Comment: One thing though... are you adding new methods with these decorators?

Comment: @plalx yes, for example a tranlatable error have a method attached to translatable so you can retrieve ther right translation for your goal language

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to add methods using decorators. How will you expose the Translatable behavior if the last applied decorator was Viewable? A Viewable doesn't have the Translatable methods in it's contract.

Comment: @plalx, I was thinking of Factories to be the only way to create those nested objects in the right order. As well as I was thinking of checking certain types in constructors inputs and if the inputs were not of those certain types the special decorator throw an error. Please notice that the language I am doing this php, so I wouldn't have to check the input types of constructors necessarily and I can check for several argument types inside the constructor itself.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how factories will solve the problem of dealing with multiple different decorator APIs?

Comment: @plalx sorry is your last comment a question?

Comment: Yes, it's a question.

Comment: @plalx sorry. My bad English! would you please re-phrase your question so I can better understand it. I am not a native speaker. Thank you